# LINQ Varbinary to C# Byte Array

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, arrays, varbinary

I am new to the whole LINQ system, i have my passwords hashed and stored in a varbinary field in my database, now i want to get that value from my database and store it in a byte array to do a comparison using LINQ.  I did it like this before:

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBytes sqlPassBinary = dr.GetSqlBytes(dr.GetOrdinal("Password"));
```

Now i want to try and apply this same concept but using LINQ this time.  I tried this but it didn't work:

```
public bool Authenticate(string user, string pass)
{
    ***LINQDataContext d = new ***LINQDataContext();

    var login = from us in d.Users
                join ur in d.UserRoles on us.UserRoleID equals ur.UserRoleID
                where us.Username == user 
                select us;

    if ((login as IEnumerable<object>).Any())
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] = login.FirstOrDefault().UserID.ToString();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserRole"] = login.FirstOrDefault().UserRole.ToString();
        byte[] sqlbinary = (byte[]) login.FirstOrDefault().Password;;

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And i get this error:
[image]

Comment: what is `login`? you need to show a full code example with all your members.

Comment: "it didn't work" tells us *very* little about what actually happened. Did it fail to compile? Did it compile but give an execution-time exception? Did it silently give you incorrect data? Please give more information. (Think about what *you'd* want to know if someone came to you with the question and asked you to help solve it.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error indicates that the collection returned by LINQ is a `System.Data.Linq.Binary` object and you cannot use it to initialize the `byte[]`, nor to convert it explicitly.

First, you need to convert it to the array, use the LINQ's built-in `ToArray()` function.

Use

```
byte[] sqlbinary = login.FirstOrDefault().Password.ToArray();
```

It should be just fine.